# Transfer octomap w/out ROS Message

Tags: ros, octomap, message, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

is there a way to transfer a octomap between two nodes without using ROS messages?

Due to high processing time I sourced out the octomap creating - and need the processed octomap in my main node. Using the octomap_msgs takes too long for high frequency use to publish it.

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262971/transfer-octomap-w/out-ros-message/) by [SirJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/30587/sirj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer your question literally: There are plenty of message-passing protocols around that you could use to transfer the octomap between processes: zeroMQ, MQTT, gRPC, etc.; however, I would be surprised if those would give you much better results than using ROS with octomap_msgs. The reason is that the message from octomap_msgs simply wraps a binary .bt/.ot file, which is exactly what you would pass around using any other protocol, so there shouldn't be any significant overhead there.

A much better idea would probably be to use nodelets, so that you don't need any inter-process communication there. Two nodelets running in the same process don't even serialize/deserialize messages, they simply pass shared pointers around.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2017-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1